# In Ruby how to create methods with sub-classes?

Tags: ruby

What I am trying to create is a program that will allow the user to enter a name, and that this name will give two messages in two different files. With the message in the second file simply being the name entered. In particular what I am self-learning to do is public class methods involving sub-classes, and my attempt at the below program is to do this. Any advice or link would be appreciated. The debugger says it's a syntax error line 37 (last line) "unexpected $end, expecting key_word end".

```
puts "Hello Friend. What is your name?"
  STDOUT.flush
$end

def self.get
  name
end

def self.name
  name = gets.chomp
end

File.open("testingruby.doc", 'w') do |file|
  if name != "David"
    file.puts "That's incorrect." + " " + name
  else
    file.puts "Hello " + name + "!" + " I hope you are well. Welcome to Ruby."
end

public_class_method :name
$end



class ExampleTwo < ExampleOne
 def self.get
   pizza
 end

def self.pizza
   piza = name
end

File.open("testingruby2.doc", 'w') do |file2|
   file2.puts(pizza)
end
end
```

Comment: Is this all of your code? What's with all of the `$end`s? Where is the global `$end` defined? Why are you constantly getting it's value?

Comment: I imagine this is not the entirety of the code. I too would be interested to learn the reason for the method invocation and `$end`.

Comment: All of the `$end`s are really just global variable accesses which are returning nil, because there is no global variable `$end`. So really, they are just a bunch of lines with a value of nil.

Comment: This is the entire code.  The multiple $end came from debugging using the compiler.  I am just starting to learn Ruby, piecing  things together as I go along.

Comment: Have you had any luck with my answer below?

Comment: Was just trying it out and replied.  A little bit of helpful.  Thanks.  It's now saying the problem is the public_class_method is undefined.

Comment: -1 I just wasted 45 minutes preparing a detailed answer to your previous question.  When I attempted to post my answer I found that you had deleted your question, and then soon after I found you reposted it here, slightly modified.  That's what the edit button is for.  In any event, everything I had written was lost.  Needless to say, I won't be going out of my way to help you in future.

Comment: @David, are you going to accept one of the answers below? Either one has clearly gone to lengths to help you resolve your issue – if one has particularly helped you, please consider accepting it.

Answer (score 0):

Your first invocation of `File.open` is missing an `end` to the block:

```
File.open("testingruby.doc", 'w') do |file|
  if name != "David"
    file.puts "That's incorrect." + " " + name
  else
    file.puts "Hello " + name + "!" + " I hope you are well. Welcome to Ruby."
  end
end
```

Remember that Ruby conditionals must be *explictly* closed. From the looks of it, you tried closing the `File.open` block without closing the conditional first, which is causing your problem.

Comment: Thanks for your comment.  Did your suggestion, now it's saying "undefined method 'public_class_method' for main: object <NoMethodError>".  Any suggestions or links on how to fix this?

Comment: What is the purpose of `public_class_method`? If you don't know why it's there, you should remove it entirely. If you're wondering about the syntax: from the looks of it, you're trying to invoke a method called `public_class_method` and pass the `:name` symbol to it. If you've defined the method elsewhere in the code, you won't receive this error... if you haven't defined it, you either 1) need to define it, or 2) remove it.

Comment: Yes, that what I was trying to do ("invoke a method called public_class_method and pass the :name symbol to it"), because I have my second class in which I am trying to pass the name entered into so that the name entered is shown in a second .doc file.  The program as is, place the name entered into the same file as shown in the first class.  It my understanding for this to occur the method and symbol must be public.  Is this correct?

Comment: I can't answer definitively unless you post the entire contents of both files. Please include the names of both files in your update. Also point out where you are defining the `public_class_method` function.

Comment: Doesn't

def self.name
  name = gets.chomp
end

do this?  And, there is nothing else.  These are new files being created.  This is just a learning exercise that I have created for myself.

Comment: I have no idea what you are referring to. If you'd like more help, you should post the entirety of your code. Otherwise, I'm inclined to vote to close this question.

Comment: Anything new with this?

Answer (score 0):

As I mentioned in a comment to your question, I wasted a considerable amount of time replying to your previous question (a slight variant of this one), which you deleted before I attempted to post my solution, in effect, pulling the rug from under my feet.  The first part of my answer explained some problems with your code.  That's gone and I have no inclination to recreate it.  The second part, which I retained, is below.  This is a suggestion for doing what you wish to achieve:

```
class ExampleOne
  def self.name
    puts "Hello Friend. What is your name?"
    your_name = gets.chomp
    if your_name != "David"
      str = "That's incorrect," + " " + your_name + "."
    else
      str = "Hello " + your_name + "!" + \
        " I hope you are well. Welcome to Ruby."
    end
    File.write("testingruby.doc", str)
    File.write("testingruby2.doc", your_name)
  end
end
```

We can test this by running it and then read the contents of the files it creates:

```
ExampleOne.name # Enter "Doug"
puts File.read("testingruby.doc")  # => That's incorrect, Doug.
puts File.read("testingruby2.doc") # => Doug

ExampleOne.name # Enter "David"
puts File.read("testingruby.doc")
  # => Hello David! I hope you are well. Welcome to Ruby.
puts File.read("testingruby2.doc") # => David
```

Instead of `File.write` I could have written:

```
  File.open("testingruby.doc", 'w') do |file|
    file.write(str)
    file.close
  end
```

Here `file.close` is optional; the file will be closed at the end of the block in any event.  Similarly, instead of `File.read` you could write:

```
  File.open("testingruby.doc", 'r') do |file|
    puts file.read
    file.close
  end
```

and, again, `file.close` is not required.

Comment: Thanks for your time and consideration.  My apologies for what occurred.